# Inserting records in loop without any unique columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table for example which does not have any identity or unique column:

```
create table tbl_test ( first_name nvarchar(255), last_name nvarchar(255),
                        [address] nvarchar(255))  
Insert tbl_test values ('Andrei','Corovei','str Meteor') 
Insert tbl_test values ('Pop','Ionut','str Meteor') 
Insert tbl_test values ('Whitehead','John','str Lunii') 
Insert tbl_test values ('Grisham','Robert','str Corcoduselor') 
Insert tbl_test values ('Eugen','Johnesco','str Prunelor')
```

I can insert the rows from the above table to a another table using below syntax:

```
select * into tbl_test_loop from tbl_test
```

This will insert all records in one shot.

Can I insert in a loop with a batch count of 2 the above results rather than at one shot without creating any Identity or rownumber function?

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and hit the `{}` code button. It adds syntax highlighting and preserves line breaks.

Comment: Why do you want a loop? What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: batches are 'usually' of the order of 10,000 or so. 2 seems rather low!!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there is some requirment like this..I have just given a demo table.but actual table will have millions of records.

Comment: no unique key == how do you know which records have already been inserted with some sort of row number??

Comment: The problem is, I don't understand what result you're aiming for - you haven't explained it well enough yet (or I'm being dense, another possibility). Could you try adding more explanation please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the target is to insert data from source table having billion rows to another table.the aim is to achieve this in minimum possible time.we are trying to do a POC where we can do inserts in batches so that if a particular batch fails,still we can go ahead inserting rest data.one way is to create a row number column in a CTE or temp table.But if we create any intermediate steps like creating temp tables and CTE,it eats lot of time.So i just needed any way by which we can transfer data from source table in batches or loops without the need to create rownum column in CTE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @loopcount int
Declare @rcount int
Declare @idn int
Declare @iteration int
Declare @strsql varchar(1000)

select @loopcount=2,@idn=1
select @rcount=count(*) from tbl_test
SET @iteration=(@rcount/@loopcount)+(@rcount%@loopcount)

while(@idn<=@iteration)
BEGIN
SET @strsql='INSERT INTO tbl_test_loop select top '+cast(@loopcount as varchar(2))+' * from tbl_test t where not exists(select * from tbl_test_loop l where l.first_name = t.first_name  and l.last_name = t.last_name  and l.[address] = t.[address])'
exec(@strsql)
select 'inserted '+cast(@loopcount as varchar(2))
SET @idn=@idn+1
END
```

Comment: Its inserting only the first 2 rows 3 times in 3 loops.Its not inserting the rest 3 rows

Comment: If you change the <> to =,it works..thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Ooops yeah you are right I am using NOT Exists means it should be =

Answer (score 0):

```
 select tbl_test.* into tbl_test_loop from tbl_test, ( select 1 as loop union select 2) v
```

Comment: Its inserting all the records twice

Comment: i want 1st 2 rows,and then next 2 rows and then the last row..in total 3 loops

Answer (score 0):

Try NTILE, no loop required:

```
select NTILE(3) OVER( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) x, * 
into tbl_test_loop 
from tbl_test
```

Comment: :Its adding a column.I wanted it to insert in 3 transactions or batches.Your code is inserting all 5 rows in one shot.

Comment: @satyajit - I think we're struggling to understand *what benefit* doing it in multiple batches is meant to provide - it doesn't make sense. At the end, you're still going to have 5 rows in the second table, and rows in a table are unordered.